# How to track the IP Address using Google sheets and Forms

Tags: google-apps-script

is there anyone who knows how to track the ip address usong google sheets and forms? i'm doing attendance tracker (log in,log out with timestamp). Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can get the ip address in google sheets or forms.  However if you use Jot Forms you can track ip address. However, it's becoming less and less valuable each day as more and more people connect via vpn. If you track my ip address right now you would think I was in New York.  Trust me I'm not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to capture the IP Address to google spreadsheet via google web form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831182/i-need-to-capture-the-ip-address-to-google-spreadsheet-via-google-web-form)