# Get IP Address on Google Form submission

Tags: javascript

I was searching for a script to capture the IP Address of the person who submits the Form. I ended up writing this code in the response sheet:

```js
/*
 * Global Variables
 */
// Form
var formId = 'FromID';
// Sheet
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
var columnName = 'IP Address';

// Responses starting row
var startRow = 2;

function UploadIPAddress_FromSheet(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
    var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

    for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i][0] && !data[i][columnIndex]) {
          
            var ip = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api6.ipify.org?format=json')).ip;
  
             sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(ip);
        }
    }
}
```

This works as expected in that when I run the script manually it populates the "IP Address" column of the last response row with my IP address.  However, when I submit the form with a trigger to run the script, it does the same but with the Google server IP address.

Any idea how I can achieve the first output by the Form submission?

Many thanks

Comment: Tracking of submission IP addresses is not supported in Google Forms, confirmed by a Google employee in [this thread](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4086880?hl=en).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to capture the IP Address to google spreadsheet via google web form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831182/i-need-to-capture-the-ip-address-to-google-spreadsheet-via-google-web-form)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. You have to look into alternative form services.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The same thing happens even without form submission. I have this simple script: function GetIP(){return ip = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api6.ipify.org?format=json')).ip;}. When I call this function for a cell in the sheet I get the server's IP address and not mine.  Is there a way to get my IP address or that is not possible either. Many thanks.

Comment: @Sabba do you see your ip on https://jsfiddle.net/Lgov48an/1/ ?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You asked me if the my I address was showing using your formula and I replied that yes it would. Does that help?